# EntityFramework6 - Error 42703: column Extent1... not found

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, entity-framework-6, npgsql

so I encountered this Error:

```
"ExceptionMessage": "42703: column Extent1.Employee_mavnr does not exist"
```

and after some Google Searches, I still can't figure the exact problem out. Most explanation I found, were about column names and i quite changed them a few times now, but it is still not working.

My Database looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_process
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Process_Id_seq"'::regclass),
  name text,
  description text,
  submitter text,
  created date,
  CONSTRAINT "PrimaryKey-ID" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
CREATE TABLE v_employee
(
  mavnr text NOT NULL, -- Mitarbeiter Nummer
  vorname text,
  nachname text,
  abt text,
  email text,
  del boolean,
  CONSTRAINT employee_pkey PRIMARY KEY (mavnr)
)
```

And my current Model which generates this error looks like this:

```
 [Table("tbl_process", Schema = "public")]
    public class Process
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }

        public string description { get; set; }

        public DateTime created { get; set; }

        public string submitter { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }


    [Table("v_employee", Schema = "public")]
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public string mavnr { get; set; }

        public string vorname { get; set; }

        public string nachname { get; set; }

        public string abt { get; set; }

        public string email { get; set; }

        public bool del { get; set; }
    }
```

The Request for the Employees runs through without any Error, only the Process Table is making errors. I hope someone see what is wrong with it.

Thanks for your help, really appreciate it

Edit:

The submitter column in the process table should link to the mavnr from the employee table

Comment: What is your code for getting the data?

Comment: Also, you have a navigation property `Employee` in the `Process` class, but no column in the table to make the link.

Comment: @DavidG  private IAMServiceContext db = new IAMServiceContext();

        // GET: api/Processes
        public IQueryable<Process> GetProcesses()
        {
            return db.Processes;
        }

this i my code to get it. How exactly do i make the link, does they have to be named the same?

Comment: As @DavidG said, you have a navigation property but no foreign key property for that navigation. You need to add a FK property and mark the navigation property with [ForeignKey("keyname")] attribute

Comment: @DejanJanjušević thank you very much, I followed a tutorial of microsoft and they didn't use the ForeignKey property, so i was confused. You Guys saved my Day

Comment: @DavidG if you post your comment as answer i will mark it as solved

thanks again both of you, I appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DavidG said in the above comment, you have a navigation property but no foreign key property for that navigation.

You need to add a FK property and mark the navigation property with [ForeignKey("keyname")] attribute:

```
[Table("tbl_process", Schema = "public")]
public class Process
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public string description { get; set; }

    public DateTime created { get; set; }

    public string submitter { get; set; }

    public string mavnr { get; set; } // <-- add this foreign key

    [ForeignKey("mavnr")] // <-- decorate the navigation property like this (or is "submitter" your FK?)
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}


[Table("v_employee", Schema = "public")]
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public string mavnr { get; set; }

    public string vorname { get; set; }

    public string nachname { get; set; }

    public string abt { get; set; }

    public string email { get; set; }

    public bool del { get; set; }
}
```